# SXA search filter by custom value

Tags: sxa, search-facet

I need to pass in a value that's being pulled from the contact db for each user on the site to filter search results. We only want users to see search results that are in the proper context.

Is it possible to add a facet to the url programatically before the js api call happens? I've tried to do this by adding a pipeline method just after ProcessItem but it doesn't work. Is there another part of the pipeline I should look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like this out of the box. I would suggest writing Search Token, SXA has a couple of pre-defined ones. Just click Build query in the scope item, type SXA and you will see something like this:

[image]

You can write your custom one which will take data from Contact Database for each user. And the results will be filtered by those values. Take a look at `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.TokenResolution.Pipelines.ResolveTokens`. Investigating `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.TokenResolution.Pipelines.ResolveTokens.ResolveTokensProcessor` base processor class might also help.

Comment: Thanks for the response! To confirm though, these tokens are only available in SXA 1.7 and above right? We're currently on 1.4.

Comment: Damn.... 1.4!? It was like in the previous century:) You should update as fast as you can!